# Getting HazelcastSerializationException where ArrayDataSerializableFactory is not be able to create an instance for id

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am facing an issue when my web application is querying to Hazelcast cache to get data, HazelcastSerializationException is being thrown. We are using hazelcast-all-3.6.6.jar.

Following is stack trace for the same collected from server logs -

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ArrayDataSerializableFactory@5e5caba is not be able to create an instance for id: 100 on
factoryId: -32
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponseOrThrowException(InvocationFuture.java:360) ~[hazelcast-all-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:225) ~[hazelcast-all-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:204) ~[hazelcast-all-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.addResultsOfPagingPredicate(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:503) ~[hazelcast-all-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.MapQueryEngineImpl.queryAllPartitionsWithPagingPredicate(MapQueryEngineImpl.java:388) ~[hazelcast-all-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.values(MapProxyImpl.java:635) [hazelcast-all-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6]
```

This exception is in Hazelcast classes where, after getting QueryResultRow, It fails to do serialization. Following is code snippet for the same where it fails exactly:

```
QueryResultRow row = (QueryResultRow)i$1.next();
Object key = this.toObject(row.getKey());
Object value = this.toObject(row.getValue());
```

Following is implementation of toObject() method:

```
protected Object toObject(Object obj) {
   return this.serializationService.toObject(obj);
}
```

Comment: What are the objects stored in the result? Any custom serialization involved?

Comment: Hazelcast cache stores String as key and objects of Custom class as Value in my application. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Custom class is serializable as well. In fact, there is no exception when application runs on local machine.

Comment: Sure that both nodes run the same Java and Hazelcast version? The exception sounds like you might have an async serialization.
PS: yes thanks, that's what I was asking

Comment: Same artifact is there on all the nodes which implies having same Hazelcast version. Java version is also same on all the nodes.

Comment: Can you try updating to latest Hazelcast version?

Comment: let me give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I have no updates at the moment as this issue has been put on hold.